# Clicking Field with AutoIt in an ERP program

Tags: automation, autoit

Here is my scenario:

I am starting AutoIT recorder. I record using the keyboard since using the mouse causes the script to stop most of the time or does something inaccurate when started after that.

What I do is I open up an Excel template I have created. I then go into an ERP system and copy a few columns which I paste into Excel. After these columns are inserted, a few more columns are calculated from the formulas I have previously inserted.

The problem is that when I am into the ERP system I have selected a specific time period...Let's say 1st November till 31st November. I then save the excel and use the Excel option to send an email to specific people with the excel report attached.

I compile the autoit script to an exe and I have a scheduler which starts the exe. **The problem is that I need a way to change the date** to December, then January and so on... How do I do that using AutoIt? Can it be done at all?

This is how the date looks like in the ERP program:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to use: Send, ControlSend, ControlCommand, ControlSetText ? Besides, you could stop the mouse from being moved while your script is active - see BlockInput.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first inspect the program using AutoIt Window Info tool: drag the target icon to the filed you wish to click on - use [ControlClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm). Let's take an example with Excel, it says the title is: "Book1 - Excel" and the ID of the button I chose is "1001", the script will be:

```
ControlClick("Book1 - Excel", "", 1001)
```

If there isn't any ID, it will be harder as you'll need to [MouseClick](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm) by coordinates which is prone for errors...

**Changing the time:** in order to change the date picking according to the current month you'll need something like:

```
Local $stringInCell = ControlGetText("ERP title", "text in ERP window (can be empty)", controlID)
If @MON = StringLeft($stringInCell, 2) Then
    ControlClick("ERP title", "text in ERP window (can be empty)", controlID)
EndIf
```

Where [@MON](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm#@MON) is a macro, and [StringLeft](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringLeft.htm) is like starts with, assuming the first 2 characters are good for you (e.g. January is 01).

Comment: However how would I make AutoIT change the date every month automatically ?

Comment: You can get the date using https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_NowDate.htm and decide in the script accordingly what to click, in your case it's something like 'if(line.StartsWith(monthNumber)) Then clickCell'

Comment: It seems that I have to use a different menu in the ERP system to retrieve the info I need. It's pretty much the same because I have to click to select the month." I have this: if @MON = 12 Then" and i do the clicking....however this works only for clicking the month filter. The box that opens I can't get the ID because if I click outside of it, it closes. Even If I do it with clicking...it only opens the filter and after that doesn't click the month I want....Any suggestions ?